# Yii2 fullcalendar not show events before 09:00:00 in calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, fullcalendar

I have a yii2 project and i would like show events in calendar.
Yii2 fullcalendar not show events before 09:00:00, but after all good.
After 09:00:00 all good.
I'll show you my code, which works fine.
Thank you for your help.

```
echo yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
        'options' => [
            'lang' => 'hu',
        ],
        'events' => $events,
        'clientOptions' =>[
            'header' => [
                'right'=>'month,agendaWeek'
            ],
            'displayEventTime' => false,
            'height' => 'auto',
            'minTime' => '06:00:00',
            'maxTime' => '20:00:00',
            'html' => true,
            'eventClick' => new \yii\web\JsExpression($JSEventClick),
            'eventRender' => new \yii\web\JsExpression($JSEventRender),
        ],
    ));
```

$events array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => yii2fullcalendar\models\Event Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => TEST TITLE
            [allDay] => 2020-03-23 08:30:00
            [start] => 2020-03-23 08:30:00
            [end] => 2020-03-23 9:30:00
        )
}
```

Comment: `[allDay] => 2020-03-23 08:30:00` makes no sense. `allDay` is a boolean, its value can be either `true` or `false`.

Comment: Even allowing for that, I can't reproduce your problem with the data provided: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNXPRZb

Comment: The only time I can think of where you might have such a problem is in the "month" view, where you've got an event which starts on one day, and ends before 9am on a following day. That's when this rule would apply: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/nextDayThreshold . But in the data given in your question, the event starts and ends on the same day, so the nextDayThreshold rule is not used.

Comment: Thank you for answers.
I found the problem.
This is not good:
[end] => 2020-03-23 9:30:00
This is good:
[end] => 2020-03-23 09:30:00
¯\_(ツ)_/¯